# Are time-zones in sync between Windows and .NET

Tags: .net, timezone

Occasionaly Windows time zones are updated (e.g. http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/970653). Does this also updates time zone information inside .NET framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

See the following quote from this [blog post on TimeZone from the .NET Base Class Team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2006/10/03/System.TimeZone2-Starter-Guide-_5B00_Kathy-Kam_5D00_.aspx).

> The best part about this is that… if you are on an Vista machine… all of those functionality will have Vista’s Dynamic Time Zone support, because **our calculations are done with the time zone data available on your OS**.

This to me seems to indicate that the .NET Framework time zone info should be in sync with whatever the hosting OS provides.